# Split String into Columns by two character markers

Tags: regex, r, string, tidyr

All, I have searched around and can't find the answer on how to do this. I am relatively new to R and have not used regular expresions before but bascially I have some data put into a field like this:

```
"#Route - 6 #Category - PARKING #Details - Parking issues#Result - MOVED ON #Vehicle Type - Mercedes "
```

I basically want to be able to split the string up into different elements, so each category after the # has it own column.

I tried using the tidyr package and initially tried:

```
string %>% separate(Description, into  =  c("Route","Details","Result","License No",
                        "Vehicle Desciption"),
                sep = "\n#", remove =F, extra =  "drop")
```

But realised I only wanted the data after the "-". I tried inserting a "-" in the code but it didn't work. Does anyone know how I can split the string ideally between the "-" and the "#".

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

In one line:

```
> gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$","",gsub(".*?[-]","",unlist(strsplit(str,"#"))))
[1] ""               "6"              "PARKING"        "Parking issues" "MOVED ON"       "Mercedes"
```

Or separate for better understanding:
Break string by "#":

```
a = unlist(strsplit(str,"#"))
```

Remove what is before the "-"

```
b = gsub(".*?[-]","",a)
```

Remove leading and trailing spaces:

```
gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$","",b)
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to split the string up nicely and also remove the /n because the text is imported on different lines. However I have multiple rows in a data frame like this I wish to spread across columns to make them multiple variables. Can I do it inside the data frame?  so have data like this: df = (date, hour, string) and I would like df=(date,hour,string, Route, Details, Result, License No, Vehicle Description).

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following:

```
strsplit(x, ' *#[^-]+- *')[[1]][2:6]
# [1] "6"              "PARKING"        "Parking issues" "MOVED ON"       "Mercedes"
```

To supply the column names you desire, I suppose you could do something like:

```
mat <- matrix(strsplit(x, ' *#[^-]+- *')[[1]][2:6], ncol=5, byrow=T)
colnames(mat) <- c('Route', 'CAT', 'Details', 'Result', 'Vehicle Description')

#      Route CAT       Details          Result     Vehicle Description
# [1,] "6"   "PARKING" "Parking issues" "MOVED ON" "Mercedes"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str1, '(?<=-\\s)\\w+(?:\\s*\\w+){0,}')[[1]]
#[1] "6"              "PARKING"        "Parking issues" "MOVED ON"      
#[5] "Mercedes"      

 str_extract_all(str2, '(?<=-\\s)\\w+(?:\\s*\\w+){0,}')[[1]]
 #[1] "6"                          "PARKING"                   
 #[3] "Parking issues"             "MOVED ON"                  
 #[5] "Mercedes"                   "Parking issues are present"
 #[7] "MOVED ON"                   "Mercedes"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "#Route - 6 #Category - PARKING #Details - Parking issues#Result - MOVED ON #Vehicle Type - Mercedes "

str2 <- "#Route - 6 #Category - PARKING #Details - Parking issues#Result - MOVED ON #Vehicle Type - Mercedes #Details - Parking issues are present#Result - MOVED ON #Vehicle Type - Mercedes "
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to split the string up. I have multiple rows in a data frame like this I wish to spread across columns to make them multiple variables. Can I do it inside the data frame? so have data like this: df = (date, hour, string) and I would like df=(date,hour,string, Route, Details, Result, License No, Vehicle Description). The way the extract works seems to imply I can.

Comment: @MrMonkeyBum It should work for multiple rows as well.  Based on your new dummy example `do.call(rbind,str_extract_all(as.character(df$string), pat))` and then cbind with the original dataset with the new column names.